# Is it possible to rename a file and preserve cvs history?

Tags: file, versioning, cvs, tortoisecvs

I have a file that has been there for more than 1 year with periodic modifications. Now I have to rename this file, my only problem is that I don't want to lose the cvs history for this file. The history is important to me because I need to use it as a reference for my changes. I searched for 'cvs rename' but I didn't find one. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: More info on this in this StackOverflow post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133721/move-a-file-in-cvs-without-resetting-the-revision-number

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good way to do this. You can find the file in the cvs repository and rename that file. The drawback is this will be the name of the file for all versions not just going forward.

You can also copy the repository file to a file with the new name. Drawbacks to that too. It just depends on just exactly how you have things set up.

Comment: Agreed. It's just one of the limitations of CVS unfortunately. Either of the approaches above will work if you don't care about the fact that you are changing history. ie. if you will never check out old versions of code.